# React native 'BottomSheetModalInternalContext' cannot be null

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-ref, react-ref

I'm using the [BottomSheetModal](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/modal/usage) to display a list of all countries in a bottom sheet. But I get the error message `'BottomSheetModalInternalContext' cannot be null!` when navigating to the screen that includes the bottom modal.

I assume that the error occurs because I initialize the ref (`bottomSheetModalRef`) with null, but I don't know how else I can create the ref without passing in null.

Excerpt of the full error message

```
'BottomSheetModalInternalContext' cannot be null!

This error is located at:
    in ForwardRef(BottomSheetModal)
    in ForwardRef(BottomSheetModal) (at CountryPicker.tsx:89)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (at CountryPicker.tsx:74)
    ...
```

```
//CountryPicker.tsx
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'
import { BottomSheetFlatList, BottomSheetModal } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet'

import { Box, Text } from '../../theme/theme'

interface Props {
  onCountrySelected: (country: string) => void
  value: string
}

interface CountryProps {
  flag: string
  name: string
  alpha3Code: string
}
const Country = (country: CountryProps) => (
  <Box>
    <Text>{country.name}</Text>
  </Box>
)

const CountryPicker: React.FC<Props> = ({ onCountrySelected, value }) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState<CountryProps[]>([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null)

  const handlePresentPress = () => {
    if (bottomSheetModalRef.current) bottomSheetModalRef.current.present()
  }
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['20%', '40%'], [])

  const getAllCountries = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const res = await axios.get(
      'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;flag;alpha3Code',
    )
    const data = await res.data
    setCountries(data)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  const getCountryByCode = async (code: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${code}?fields=name;flag;alpha3Code`,
    )
    const data = await res.data
    setCountries(data)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  const renderCountry = (country: CountryProps) => {
    return (
      <Country
        flag={country.flag}
        name={country.name}
        alpha3Code={country.alpha3Code}
      />
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCountries()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Box>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePresentPress}>
        <Box marginVertical="xs">
          <Box
            paddingVertical="inputS"
            paddingHorizontal="inputM"
            borderRadius="s"
            backgroundColor="inputBG"
            borderColor="inputBG"
            borderWidth={2}
          >
            <TextInput placeholder="Country" value={value} editable={false} />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <BottomSheetModal ref={bottomSheetModalRef} snapPoints={snapPoints}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <BottomSheetFlatList
            data={countries}
            keyExtractor={(item: CountryProps) => item.alpha3Code}
            renderItem={(countries) => renderCountry(countries.item)}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
            onRefresh={getAllCountries}
            bounces={false}
          />
        )}
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </Box>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})

export default CountryPicker
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

confirm you surround your `App.tsx` file with `BottomSheetModalProvider`

```js
  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      ....
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  );
```

Comment: Oh my god, Can't believe I overlook that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this error can occur (as I've just encountered) is if your BottomSheetModal is inside of a Portal component.

If this is the case, simply move the BottomSheetModal out of the Portal to fix the issue.

You may also be able to add a BottomSheetModalProvider wrapper within the Portal, but I would strongly suggest against this.